# Stored procedure error 'Invalid Column'

Tags: .net, sql

I want to change the below C# code from ordinary SQL to a stored procedure but it always show error on columns that they are `Invalid Column`. What is wrong with the stored procedure?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_AdminRegPage1]
     (@VendorId VARCHAR)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT WorksPackage,MajorWorks FROM dbo.RegPage1 WHERE Vendor_Id = @VendorId;
END

protected void DisplayRecord()
{
     SqlConnection SqlCon = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString());
     string sql = "SELECT WorksPackage,MajorWorks from RegPage1 
                                                 WHERE Vendor_ID='"+lblPage1ID.Text+"'";
     var da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, SqlCon);
     var ds = new DataSet();

     da.Fill(ds);

     if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
     {
        txtMajorPackages.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["WorksPackage"].ToString();
        txtRegP1Works.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["MajorWorks"].ToString();
     }
}
```

Comment: Where is the code that calls the proc?

Comment: Could there be another `RegPage1` table in a different schema? What column is being reported as Invalid? And we may need to see the calling code.

Comment: What is the error? Does there any data exist? What is the data type of your VendorId  column?

Comment: If you're working in a case sensitive collation, then `Vendor_ID` and `Vendor_Id` aren't the same column.

Comment: Sorry.still I am not write code for calling the SP.My question is that the 'SELECT' command is working fine then why it show error as 'Invalid column name WorksPackage' in SQL editor?

Comment: Sounds like the name of that column is something different. Check the column name in sql server

Comment: I think column name "WorksPackage","MajorWorks"  did not match with column names of your table . pls check that first

Comment: What shows an error? If you are talking about intellisense just ignore it and try it. You may need to refresh the cache (`Ctrl` + `Shift` + `R`). Also declare a length for your `varchar` parameter as the length defaults to 1.

Comment: Also what SQL editor are you using? SSMS or Visual Studio?

Comment: @MartinSmith : I am using SSMS, now the problem is solved after ignore the intellisense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should do the job

```
public void DisplayRecord()
{
    SqlDataReader rdr = null;

    // create and open a connection object
    SqlConnection SqlCon = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString());

    try
    {

        SqlCon.Open();

        // 1. create a command object identifying
        // the stored procedure
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(
            "usp_AdminRegPage1", SqlCon);

        // 2. set the command object so it knows
        // to execute a stored procedure
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        // 3. add parameter to command, which
        // will be passed to the stored procedure
        cmd.Parameters.Add(
            new SqlParameter("@VendorId", lblPage1ID.Text));

        // execute the command
        rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        // iterate through results, printing each to console
        while (rdr.Read())
        {
            txtMajorPackages.Text = rdr["WorksPackage"];
            txtRegP1Works.Text = rdr["MajorWorks"];
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
    finally
    {
        SqlCon.Close();
    }
}
```

Example taken from this website 
 http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorials/AdoDotNet/Lesson07.aspx

Comment: Thanks MVCKarl.This will help me to call the SP.

Comment: Please tick or uptick if it helped you. Thanks